# How to select specific item from BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>?

Tags: c#, key-value, bindinglist

```
BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> properties = new BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

Code above stores around 10-30 objects `as KeyValuePair<string, string>`

I need to somehow select an element let's say with key "id"

How do I go about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
properties.Select(k => k.Key == "id").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I believe BindingList Class doesnt have Select method :\

Comment: If you can't see the select method in your intellisense, you need to include System.Linq :)

Answer (score 0):

`BindingList` does not directly implement `IEnumerable` so `FirstOrDefault()` (LINQ to objects) will not work, even when using `System.Linq`. You need to target the underlying collection. The following worked for me:

```
var myObject = ( (IEnumerable<SomeObjectType>) myBindingSource.List ).FirstOrDefault( d => d.SomeProperty == "some property value" );
```